# HttpWebRequest works but HttpClient doesn't?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to connect to a 3rd party WebApi and have created several unit tests to determine the functionality of said WebApi. My initial test used `System.Net` and did something like the following ...

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(commonUrl +
    "api/controller/action?value=" + value);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = 0;
request.Method = "POST";
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

This returns an expected response and everything is ok, however I was later asked to use `System.Net.Http` instead so attempting to something like the following ...

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(commonUrl) };
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() 
{ 
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value", value) 
};
var response = client.PostAsync("api/controller/action", 
    new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData)).Result;
```

Unfortunately though, the response `StatusCode` comes back with `System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound` Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the `WebRequest` version you are using query parameters to specify the value while in the `HttpClient` you are posting to the body. I'm not sure this is the problem but would recommend you use Fiddler, http://www.telerik.com/fiddler, to observe the request/response and diagnose from there.